# Grammatical or not?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, punctuation, syntactic-analysis

Can I say that this sentence is correct, (grammar wise)?

Saying that "We will hold he and Iran accountable for any attack on Iran seems wrong, but it makes sense. Can I say that it is grammatical?

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is he and Iran correct? That is my concern?

No, it should be *him and Iran*, then you indicate you will hold both *him* and *Iran* accountable. Some clarification on personal pronouns when acting as subject and objects [can be found here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-personal-i-me-you-him-it-they-etc). To answer the question in the comment, yes *him* is used as an object, whereas *he* is used as a subject.

> Should accountable for be accountable of?

No, [*to hold someone accountable for something*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hold+accountable) is correct.

Comment: The general rule for any sentence with "him and I" or "her and me" or anything like that is that you should be able to remove one of the subjects and still have the other be correct. The phrase "hold he accountable" isn't correct, but "hold him accountable" is.

Comment: I can say that I now  understand this concept for the first time in my life. Thank u

Comment: @mathlearner I've added a link in my answer (to an article by Cambridge Dictionary) where they explain it quite clearly with examples.

Comment: I will give it a look now

Comment: Heavenly great .. Can I ask more questions about grammar here?

Comment: @mathlearner Many basic grammar questions are better suited for [the English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), take a look there too.